# How can one count randomly white-spaced delimited values from a file in Fortran?

Tags: file, io, fortran

If one has a file containing, for example:

```
1 2 3   4    5
6  7  8  9  10
   11    12   13
14 15
16             17
        18
  19  20
```

How can one get the correct number of integers (in the given example, 20) from counting them in the file in Fortran?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little program wot I wrote for this problem.  I've subjected it to a tiny battery of tests.  It should be fairly clear what the program and subroutine are doing but if you want any explanation of what is going on, ask.  If you spot any errors, fix them.

```
PROGRAM test
  USE iso_fortran_env
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER :: cnt, filstat
  CHARACTER(len=132) :: aline  ! change the length if you want to

  cnt = 0
  OPEN(101,file='data.txt')

  DO 
     READ(101,'(a132)',iostat=filstat) aline
     IF (filstat/=0) EXIT
     CALL get_int(cnt,aline)
  END DO

  WRITE(*,*) 'counted ', cnt, 'integers'
  CLOSE(101)

CONTAINS

  RECURSIVE SUBROUTINE get_int(cnt, str)
    INTEGER, INTENT(inout) :: cnt
    CHARACTER(*), INTENT(in) :: str
    ! Local variables
    CHARACTER(len= 10), PARAMETER :: digits = '0123456789'
    INTEGER :: d1, os, n

    ! First strip off any leading spaces
    d1 = SCAN(str,digits)
    IF (d1==0) THEN ! no digit was found
       RETURN
    END IF

    ! Read the first integer on the line
    READ(str(d1:),*) n
    cnt = cnt+1

    ! Figure out how many character positions to skip over
    os = INT(LOG10(REAL(n)))+1

    ! Recurse
    CALL get_int(cnt,str(d1+os+1:))
  END SUBROUTINE get_int

END PROGRAM TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

Normally you should first tell us what you have tried so far. But anyway.

One solution that I came up with is to create an array that is clearly larger, set all of them to a value that is not valid, then read in from the file.

Make sure that you capture the `iostat` parameter, otherwise your program will crash.

Then by looking at the first occurrence of that value, you can deduce the size (and you have the values there already):

```
program read_data
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(100) :: d
    integer :: s, err
    d = -9999
    open(unit=100, file='data.txt', action='READ', status='OLD')
    read(100, *, iostat=err) d
    s = 0
    do
        s = s + 1
        if ((s == size(d)) .or. (d(s+1) == -9999)) exit
    end do
    if (s == size(d)) then
         print *, "We might have missed some..."
    end if
    write(*, '(5I5)') d(1:s)
    close(100)
end program read_data
```

Now this isn't a very good program. You're wasting memory (large array) and to scale up you have to change the code and re-compile.

I'll think about that a bit more later.

Comment: Upon an end of file condition, all items in the input list of a read statement become undefined (F2008 9.11.3 p1 (3)).  The references to `d` after the read statement are therefore non-conforming.

Comment: If you do not want to rely on the iostat error return result you could `read()d(:1) ; rewind ; read()d(:2) ; rewind.. etc until you encounter an error, then the last error-free read gives your result.